# One of the pirate stories that [ was / were ] written

Tags: pronouns

> *Treasure island* is one of the best pirate stories that **was/were** ever written.

If I use **was** then will this sentence become wrong? The subject **treasure island** is singular, I think we should use **was** only.

Also, **one of** takes a plural noun after it, so I think we should use a singular helping verb.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, it should be *were* or *have been*: TI is a member of the set of best  stories.

> Of all stories *(plural)* which {were / have been} written, TI is one of the best.

However, this jars with *one*; what lurks behind this formula is a slight hedge on the statement that TI is the best story, so most people will use *was / has been*. This is so common that it is in practical terms the 'right' way to say it.

When I run into constructions like this, I sidestep; I refuse to cast it as a relative clause and just write:

> *Treasure Island* is one of the best stories ever written.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it becomes wrong. "That" refers to the pirate stories which are plural. Therefore you need to use "were" in the subclause.