# "One of his good traits [ comes / come ] to my mind is his honesty"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

One of my exercises was to spot errors in sentences.

> Q: One of his good traits comes to my mind is his honesty.
>
> A: The word *comes* should be replaced with *come.*

Is it correct? *One* (singular) should be paired with *comes,* shouldn't it?

Comment: Related: [One of the pirate stories that \[ was / were \] written](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69046/3281)

Comment: Best should come in place of good..... After 'one of' adjective in superlative degree should be used

Answer (score 4):

I would think it should be "One of his good traits **that** comes to my mind is his honesty." "Comes" is certainly more correct than "come" as the subject is "one of his traits" and not "traits".

Answer (score -2):

If you said "One of his good traits" it's plural, because youa are talking about "his good traits", it's the same as "One of them".